# Alternative to Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

I am looking to parse a steam web page in example "bob"

http://steamcommunity.com/id/bob/games?tab=all

Once his game list exceeds 10 items I can not parse this URL anymore to grab his game list, and steam grabs the information to fill the list with JS.  I originally used Simple HTML DOM Parser, and it worked perfectly for my past projects, however I need something else to parse this content well, what should I use?

My webpage parsing this content is coded with PHP

Comment: Can you give an example of a user with more than 10 items in the list?

Comment: Sorry @icktoofay I have edited the URL in my post, this was viewing his recent games not his complete list

Comment: hi @Dagon while using their API it gives access to the users URL, Avatar, and so forth, not a list of their games.  I am looking to use the URL given to parse their game list, but needed the added tool of a parser to accomplish this.  If I'm wrong please correct me, thanks!